# Работа с Api картой Yandex. Center по названию города

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Работаю с картами от yandex. Если центр карты указываю вот так

```
center: [55.76, 37.64],
```

Показывает нормально Москву. А как сделать так чтобы работала по названию города? Например вот так.

```
center: center: "Москва",
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Делайте запрос к [геокодеру](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geocode-docpage/). Из ответа берете координаты, по которым центруете карту.

Готовый пример [отсюда](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/)

```
// Инициализация карты из результата геокодирования
var myMap;
ymaps.geocode('Москва').then(function (res) {
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(),
        zoom : 10
    });
});
```

Comment: Серьезно? все так сложно? блин в google тупо вбиваешь и все, а тут нужно парсить json ответ от геокодера.

Comment: @duddeniska в парсинге json нет ничего сложного

Comment: @duddeniska Привел пример из документации. Ничего там сложного нету, на мой взгляд

Comment: Спасибо помогли!